# Unit test waiting for SUT local ThreadPool work item to complete

Tags: c#, multithreading, unit-testing, asynchronous, threadpool

How do I force a unit test to wait for a thread to complete in a public method of the sut. The action within the thread pool work item is all local within the method.

The method to test is something like this:

```
public void Func()
{
    ThreadPool.QueueWorkItem(o => 
    { 
        Blah();
        BlahBlah();
    }
}
```

So how do I wait for `Blah()` and `BlahBlah()` to finish before I do my mock verifications without using a `Thread.CurrentThread.Join()`?

Comment: Is modification of `Func` signature possible? Also check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520179/wait-until-all-threads-teminated-in-threadpool

Comment: Ideally no. This is older code that we are just building on top of. Is there any other way to accomplish this without changes to method signatures?

Comment: you can use optional parameters, as I've described in the answer. You only need to recompile your solution