# Select Records from Sql Server Using Different Thread

Tags: c#, sql-server, multithreading

I Created a Stored Procedure with Start and End Index to Fetch Rows in between

For E.g

```
Create Procedure ProcA
@StartIndex int,
@EndIndex int
As
Begin
Select * from Table A where Rowno between @StartIndex and @EndIndex
End
```

Now I need to Fetch Rows from C# using Multiple Threads simultaneously,

Here is my Code,

```
public static DataTable ReadRecord(int startindex)
{
       SqlConnection SqlConn = new SqlConnection(Connectionstr);
       if (SqlConn.State == ConnectionState.Closed) 
       {
           SqlConn.Open();
       }
       DataTable Dt = new DataTable();
       SqlCommand SqlCmd = new SqlCommand("USP_InstinctBPDataTest", SqlConn);
       SqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

       SqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SRow", startindex);
       SqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ERow", startindex + 2499);

       SqlDataAdapter Da = new SqlDataAdapter();
       Da.SelectCommand = SqlCmd;
       Da.Fill(Dt);
       return Dt;
}
```

I have Tried Creating Multiple Thread Like,

```
List<ThreadStart> threadStartsList = new List<ThreadStart>();


ThreadStart ts = delegate() { ReadRecord(1); };
threadStartsList.Add(ts);
ThreadStart ts1 = delegate() { ReadRecord(2501); };
threadStartsList.Add(ts1);


Thread[] tsarr = new Thread[2];
int i = 0;
foreach (ThreadStart tsl in threadStartsList)
{
    tsarr[i] = new Thread(tsl);
    tsarr[i].Start();
    i++;
}

for (int j = 0; j < tsarr.Length; j++)
{
    tsarr[j].Join();
}
```

I am using .Net framework 3.5. I need to run the thread simultaneously and wait for it to finish process. But i m getting exception about connection pool reached max without running.

and I cannot use lock here because all the variables i m using inside "ReadRecord" method cannot be shared with other process and cannot wait for one thread to release all the lock variable.

Comment: why do you want to get your data this way? Because it´s faster?  I don´t think you will get any performance benefits with this approach! And if you want paging have a look at this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tx1c9c2f.aspx

Comment: Perhaps a better approach would be to retrieve all the data into one dataset, which you could store as a static variable in your program, then create a method to read rows from that dataset instead of going back to the database multiple times.

Comment: i need to get different set of data using single Stored procedure.. for e.g Top 1 to 2500 --one set & 2501 to 5000 another set simaltaneously

Answer (score 0):

I dont know your business requirements but spawning a thread for each row seems overkill. But if you are going that way at least leave managing thread pool to .net.  If it is server side code you can use ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem

```
int toProcess = 10; //lets say you have 10 index
using(ManualResetEvent resetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false))
{
    var list = new List<int>();
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++) list.Add(i); // your indexes [0..10]
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
       //add each task to pool
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
           new WaitCallback(x => {
              ReadRecord(x)
              //when finished decrement count 
              if (Interlocked.Decrement(ref toProcess)==0)
                 resetEvent.Set();

           }),list[i]);
    } 

    //wait them to finish
    resetEvent.WaitOne();
}
```

[Wait until all threads finished their work in ThreadPool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520179/wait-until-all-threads-teminated-in-threadpool)

Comment: Thanks for ur valuable comment. I will try this one and update