# Multithreading not outputting all

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I have a simple program using thread pool to execute 9 tasks. Each task starts three new threads to retrieve data. Then the calling thread processes the results. They should all execute with varying times then output the results to the immediate window. But not all tasks actually output anything. I usually get 7 to 8 results. I cannot predict which results will be output; it is random. Why are not all results output?

```
Class Work3

    Sub mainLoop()

        Dim callback As New WaitCallback(AddressOf DoOneCustomer)

        For loopCt As Integer = 1 To 9

            'Data in
            Dim dataIn As New DataIn("Cust" & loopCt, loopCt)

            'run code on the thread pool
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(callback, dataIn)

        Next

    End Sub

    Function DoOneCustomer(ByVal DataIn2 As Object) As Boolean
        Dim DataIn As DataIn = CType(datain2, Datain)

        Dim Tub As New DataContainer(DataIn.CustID, DataIn.Int)

        'start new data threads
        'get data in parallel
        Dim t1 As New Thread(AddressOf GetData1)
        Dim t2 As New Thread(AddressOf GetData2)
        Dim t3 As New Thread(AddressOf GetData3)
        t1.Start(Tub)
        t2.Start(Tub)
        t3.Start(Tub)

        'join all three threads to ensure finished getting data
        t1.Join()
        t2.Join()
        t3.Join()

        If MakeDecision(Tub) Then

            'process results in-line; no new thread
            doProcessData(Tub)

        End If

        Return True

    End Function

    Function MakeDecision(ByRef Tub As DataContainer) As Boolean
        Return True
    End Function

    Sub doProcessData(ByVal myTub As DataContainer)

        Debug.Print(myTub.Data1.QBName & _
                    " End bal: " & myTub.Data1.EndBal.ToString("#,##0") & _
                    " Inv1 " & myTub.Data2.Total.ToString("#,##0") & _
                    " Inv2 " & myTub.Data3.Total.ToString("#,##0"))
    End Sub

    Sub GetData1(ByVal myTub2 As Object)
        Dim myTub As dataContainer = CType(myTub2, DataContainer)
        Dim d As New DetailData
        d.QBName = myTub.CustID
        d.BeginBal = myTub.Int * 10000 + myTub.Int
        d.EndBal = myTub.Int * 100000 + myTub.Int
        Dim Num As Integer = Calculate(myTub.Int)

        'put data
        myTub.Data1 = d
    End Sub
    Sub GetData2(ByVal myTub2 As Object)
        Dim myTub As dataContainer = CType(myTub2, DataContainer)
        Dim inv As New InvoiceData
        inv.QbCustName = myTub.CustID
        inv.TxnDate = DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, New Random(1).Next(1, 30), Now)
        inv.Total = myTub.Int * 1000 + myTub.Int
        Dim Num As Integer = Calculate(myTub.Int)

        'put data
        myTub.Data2 = inv
    End Sub
    Sub GetData3(ByVal myTub2 As Object)
        Dim myTub As dataContainer = CType(myTub2, DataContainer)
        Dim inv As New InvoiceData
        inv.QbCustName = myTub.CustID
        inv.TxnDate = DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, New Random(1).Next(1, 30), Now)
        inv.Total = myTub.Int * 100
        Dim Num As Integer = Calculate(myTub.Int)

        'put data
        myTub.Data3 = inv
    End Sub

End Class

Class DataIn
    Public Int As Integer
    Public CustID As String
    Public Sub New(ByVal _CustID As String, ByVal _Int As Integer)
        Int = _Int
        CustID = _CustID
    End Sub
    Public Sub New()
    End Sub
End Class

Class DataContainer
    Public Int As Integer
    Public CustID As String
    Public Data1 As DetailData
    Public Data2 As InvoiceData
    Public Data3 As InvoiceData
    Public Sub New(ByVal _CustID As String, ByVal _Int As Integer)
        Int = _Int
        CustID = _CustID
    End Sub
    Public Sub New()
    End Sub
End Class

Class DetailData
    Public QBName As String
    Public BeginBal As Decimal
    Public EndBal As Decimal
End Class

Class InvoiceData
    Public QbCustName As String
    Public TxnDate As Date
    Public Total As Decimal
End Class

'calculate fibonacci to increase calculation time by varying amounts
Public Function Calculate(ByVal n As Integer) As Integer
    If n <= 1 Then
        Return n
    End If
    Return Calculate(n - 1) + Calculate(n - 2)
End Function
```

Output looks like this

```
Cust1 End bal: 100,001 Inv1 1,001 Inv2 100
Cust4 End bal: 400,004 Inv1 4,004 Inv2 400
Cust2 End bal: 200,002 Inv1 2,002 Inv2 200
Cust7 End bal: 700,007 Inv1 7,007 Inv2 700
Cust6 End bal: 600,006 Inv1 6,006 Inv2 600
Cust5 End bal: 500,005 Inv1 5,005 Inv2 500
Cust8 End bal: 800,008 Inv1 8,008 Inv2 800
Cust9 End bal: 900,009 Inv1 9,009 Inv2 900
```

[.Net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZkmSYn)

Comment: in `DoOneCustomer`, is that `Tub` or `tub`?

Comment: Supposed to be `Tub`. Does that make any difference in VB.net? Anyway I changed it and got same results.

Comment: you probably  need a function call to wait for all the threads of the pool to complete (not a vb programmer, I don't know the API).

Comment: Three times `.Join` waits for all the data so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Put `Option Strict On` at the top of the source code.  Fix the bugs in your snippet.

Comment: I'm talking about the `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` calls, which also spin threads up.

Comment: @HansPassant I don't know whether you actually expected that would make a difference or whether you were just helping me improve my code. In any case, it didn't make any difference in the output

Comment: You should never call the Join method of the Thread object that represents the current thread from the current thread. This causes your app to hang because the current thread waits upon itself indefinitely,

Comment: @JackGajanan Thanks for that observation. You might want to check the code again. I'm starting a new thread and then waiting on that one. I'm not joining the current thread.

Comment: @didierc Thanks for your comment. I tried `reset.WaitOne` on each task and that worked. But that defeats the purpose of multithreading. WaitAll is not an option in the current thread as it is STA.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520179/wait-until-all-threads-teminated-in-threadpool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with Debug.Print. I think that using Debug.Print to assess my code was a flawed idea. Why should I think that the debug window can handle multiple simultaneous input.

When using MsgBox as the output, the code performs as expected. All the data is output. Multiple Msgbox windows are not a problem for VB.net.

I also tried putting a Thread.Sleep in the code. With that it works fine too. Presumably that is because the output is no longer hitting the debug window simultaneously.

So in the end the problem is not with the code per se but with the output device. The code needs to be rewritten to account for the limitations of the output device.