# C# Reading SQLite table concurrently

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite, entity-framework

The goal here is to use SQL to read a SQLite database, uncompress a BLOB field, and parse the data. The parsed data is written to a different SQLite DB using EF6. Because the size of the incoming database could be 200,000 records or more, I want to do this all in parallel with 4 C# Tasks.

SQLite is in its default SERIALIZED mode. I am converting a working single background task into multiple tasks. The SQLite docs say to use a single connection and so I am using a single connection for all the tasks to read the database:

```
using sqlite_datareader = sqlite_cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (sqlite_datareader.Read() && !Token.IsCancellationRequested)
{
     ....
}
```

However, each task reads each record of the database. Not what I want. I need each task to take the ***next*** record from the table.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

From SQLite's standpoint, it's likely the limiting factor is the raw disk or network I/O. Naively splitting the basic query into separate tasks or parts would mean more seeks, which makes things *slower*. We see, then, that the fastest way to get the raw data from the DB is a simple query over a single connection, just like the sqlite documentation says.

But now we want to do some meaningful processing on this data, and this part might benefit from parallel work. What you need to do to get good parallelization, therefore, is create a queuing system as you receive each record.

For this, you want a single process to send the one SQL statement to the sqlite database and retrieve the results from the datareader. This thread will then queue an additional task from each record as quickly as possible, such that each task acts only the received data for the one record... that is, the additional tasks neither know nor care the data came from a database or any other specific source.

The result is you'll end up with as many tasks as you have records. However, you don't have to run that many tasks all at once. You can tune it to 4 or whatever other number you want (2 * the number CPU cores is a good rule of thumb to start with). And the easiest way to do this is to turn to `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem()`.

As we do this, one thing to remember is the DataReader will mutate itself with each read. So our main thread creating the queue must also be smart enough to copy this data to a new object with each read, so the individual threads don't end up looking at data that was already changed out for a later record.

```
using sqlite_datareader = sqlite_cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (sqlite_datareader.Read())
{
    var temp = CopyDataFromReader(sqlite_datareader); 
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(a => ProcessRecord(temp));
}
```

Additionally, each task itself has some overhead. If you have enough records, you may also gain some benefit from batching up a bunch of records before sending them to the queue:

```
int index = 0;
object[] temp;
using sqlite_datareader = sqlite_cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (sqlite_datareader.Read())
{
    temp[count] = CopyDataFromReader(sqlite_datareader);
    if (++count >= 50)
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(a => ProcessRecords(temp, 50));
        count = 0;
    }
}
if (count != 0) ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(a => ProcessRecords(temp, count));
```

Finally, you probably want to do something with this data once it is no longer compressed. One option is [wait for all the items to finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520179/wait-until-all-threads-finished-their-work-in-threadpool), so you can stitch them back into a single IEnumerable of some variety (List, Array, DataTable, iterator, etc). Another is to make sure to include all of the work with the `ProcessRecord()` method. Another is to use an Event delegate to signal when each item is ready for further work.

Comment: thanks very much for the thoughts. This is one approach I had thought of. And using a single reader task with several processing tasks make sense. I was looking for a slightly easier way to go about this. You answer was great. Informative and succinct. The decompression and crunching the data is not trivial, so parallel processing only makes sense. I suspect that a single writer task to put the processed data back into a different db table is the right way to go as well.